# vue.js template inside laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, frontend, laravel-blade

in our project, for templates for Vue.js, we write components in separate Blade files using x-templates like this:

```
<script type="x/templates" id="nameOfComponent">
```

The problem I have is that x-template content loading lately after other blade file content.

this is master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>@yield('title', 'base')</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
              
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

        @stack('scripts')
        @yield('script')

    </body>
</html>
```

and this is index.blade.php

```
test home page

<my-checkbox></my-checkbox>

@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/x-template" id="checkbox-template">
        <div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check">
        <div :class="{ checkbox: true, checked: checked }"></div>
        <h1>checkbox</h1>
        <div class="title">@{{ title }}</div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script>
        Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
            template: '#checkbox-template',
            data() {
                return { checked: false, title: 'Check me' }
            },
            methods: {
                check() { this.checked = !this.checked; }
            }
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

and this is app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');



window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
    
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
    });
});
```

how can I make all content loading in the same time?
thanks.

Comment: I think this question is way underrated, thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blade file is for server rendering and vue template is for client one, that's why it's "slower". In your case you may want to hide the page till vue finishes loading. Checkout the `v-cloak` directive. For more detail: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Comment: thank you, I will check the link and try your solution.

Comment: I tried this solution and my problem is fixed,  but it make all page loaded slowly. why Vue instance take this time to be  ready? can we make it faster?

Comment: It's not just the vue instance but all the libs coming with vue as well. I know some tools such as wepack or gulp to minimize js files and help the web build/run faster. But it takes  time to get used to them.

Comment: we already use wepack in our project and we can minimize js files before  run production. thank you for your help